# flatten out webapi EF using DTO and linq- using IF/THEN

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to flatten out my webapi EF using DTO's.  So far I have the below statement working correctly.  Now I want to add a layer of complexity stating a IF/THEN.  I put a fake code in the first line of SELECT NEW SECTION.
Can someone please assist?

```
            var query = (
                        from acctTbl in db.Accounts
                        join tradeTbl in db.Trades on acctTbl.AccountID equals tradeTbl.AccountID into ts
                        from tradeTbl in ts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join mapClientAcct in db.Mapping_ClientAccounts on acctTbl.AccountID equals mapClientAcct.AccountID
                        join clientTbl in db.Clients on mapClientAcct.ClientID equals clientTbl.ClientID
                        join mapUserClient in db.Mapping_UserClients on clientTbl.ClientID equals mapUserClient.ClientID
                        join aspNetUser in db.AspNetUsers on mapUserClient.AspNetUsersID equals aspNetUser.Id
                        join mktData in db.MarketDatas on tradeTbl.MarketDataID equals mktData.MarketDataID into ms
                        from mktData in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join mktCode in db.GMI_MarketCodes on tradeTbl.GMI_MarketCodesID equals mktCode.GMI_MarketCodesID into mc
                        from mktCode in mc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join Mgrs in db.Managers on acctTbl.ManagerID equals Mgrs.ManagerID
                        join FxMkts in db.ForexMarkets on mktData.crncy equals FxMkts.CurrencySymbol into fm
                        from FxMkts in fm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where acctTbl.AccountActive == true
                                && clientTbl.ClientID == clientID
                                && aspNetUser.UserName == username
                            select new TradeDetailDTO()
                            {

                                --THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO!!!
                                IF tradeTblIdentifier == "F" THEN 'yes'
                                ELSE 'no'
                                -------------------------

                                Filedate = tradeTbl.Filedate,
                                Quantity = tradeTbl.Quantity,
                                Month = tradeTbl.Month,
                                Strike = tradeTbl.Strike,
                                PutCall = tradeTbl.PutCall,
                                Prompt = tradeTbl.Prompt,
                                StmtPrice = tradeTbl.Price,                                    
                                ShortDesc = mktCode.ShortDesc,
                                Sector = mktCode.Sector,
                                ExchName = mktCode.ExchName,
                                BBSymbol = mktData.BBSymbol,
                                BBName = mktData.Name,
                                fut_Val_Pt = mktData.fut_Val_Pt,
                                crncy = mktData.crncy,
                                fut_tick_size = mktData.fut_tick_size,
                                fut_tick_val = mktData.fut_tick_val,
                                fut_init_spec_ml = mktData.fut_init_spec_ml,
                                last_price = mktData.last_price,
                                bid = mktData.bid,
                                ask = mktData.ask,
                                px_settle_last_dt_rt = mktData.px_settle_last_dt_rt,
                                px_settle_actual_rt = mktData.px_settle_actual_rt,
                                chg_on_day = mktData.chg_on_day,
                                prev_close_value_realtime = mktData.prev_close_value_realtime,
                                AccountNumber = acctTbl.AccountNumber,
                                TradeLevel = acctTbl.TradeLevel,
                                ManagerName = Mgrs.ManagerName,
                                ManagerShortCode = Mgrs.ManagerShortCode,
                                ForexLastPrice = db.MarketDatas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BBSymbol == mktData.crncy + " BGN CURNCY") == null ? 1: db.MarketDatas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BBSymbol == mktData.crncy + " BGN CURNCY").last_price,
                                //ForexLastPrice = FxMkts.LastPrice,  ORIGINAL
                                TopdayIdentifier = "P",
                                DailyPercentage = acctTbl.DailyPercentage,
                                AccountType = acctTbl.AccountType
                            }
                    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you want something like this:

```
var query = (
                        from acctTbl in db.Accounts
                        join tradeTbl in db.Trades on acctTbl.AccountID equals tradeTbl.AccountID into ts
                        from tradeTbl in ts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join mapClientAcct in db.Mapping_ClientAccounts on acctTbl.AccountID equals mapClientAcct.AccountID
                        join clientTbl in db.Clients on mapClientAcct.ClientID equals clientTbl.ClientID
                        join mapUserClient in db.Mapping_UserClients on clientTbl.ClientID equals mapUserClient.ClientID
                        join aspNetUser in db.AspNetUsers on mapUserClient.AspNetUsersID equals aspNetUser.Id
                        join mktData in db.MarketDatas on tradeTbl.MarketDataID equals mktData.MarketDataID into ms
                        from mktData in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join mktCode in db.GMI_MarketCodes on tradeTbl.GMI_MarketCodesID equals mktCode.GMI_MarketCodesID into mc
                        from mktCode in mc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join Mgrs in db.Managers on acctTbl.ManagerID equals Mgrs.ManagerID
                        join FxMkts in db.ForexMarkets on mktData.crncy equals FxMkts.CurrencySymbol into fm
                        from FxMkts in fm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where acctTbl.AccountActive == true
                                && clientTbl.ClientID == clientID
                                && aspNetUser.UserName == username
                            select new TradeDetailDTO()
                            {

                                YesNo = tradeTbl.Identifier == "F"?"yes":"no",
                                Filedate = tradeTbl.Filedate,
                                Quantity = tradeTbl.Quantity,
                                Month = tradeTbl.Month,
                                Strike = tradeTbl.Strike,
                                PutCall = tradeTbl.PutCall,
                                Prompt = tradeTbl.Prompt,
                                StmtPrice = tradeTbl.Price,                                    
                                ShortDesc = mktCode.ShortDesc,
                                Sector = mktCode.Sector,
                                ExchName = mktCode.ExchName,
                                BBSymbol = mktData.BBSymbol,
                                BBName = mktData.Name,
                                fut_Val_Pt = mktData.fut_Val_Pt,
                                crncy = mktData.crncy,
                                fut_tick_size = mktData.fut_tick_size,
                                fut_tick_val = mktData.fut_tick_val,
                                fut_init_spec_ml = mktData.fut_init_spec_ml,
                                last_price = mktData.last_price,
                                bid = mktData.bid,
                                ask = mktData.ask,
                                px_settle_last_dt_rt = mktData.px_settle_last_dt_rt,
                                px_settle_actual_rt = mktData.px_settle_actual_rt,
                                chg_on_day = mktData.chg_on_day,
                                prev_close_value_realtime = mktData.prev_close_value_realtime,
                                AccountNumber = acctTbl.AccountNumber,
                                TradeLevel = acctTbl.TradeLevel,
                                ManagerName = Mgrs.ManagerName,
                                ManagerShortCode = Mgrs.ManagerShortCode,
                                ForexLastPrice = db.MarketDatas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BBSymbol == mktData.crncy + " BGN CURNCY") == null ? 1: db.MarketDatas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BBSymbol == mktData.crncy + " BGN CURNCY").last_price,
                                //ForexLastPrice = FxMkts.LastPrice,  ORIGINAL
                                TopdayIdentifier = "P",
                                DailyPercentage = acctTbl.DailyPercentage,
                                AccountType = acctTbl.AccountType
                            }
                    );
```

Comment: perfect... thanks it works.  Now to take it one step further, I should have put in my original question, if I have like 3 or 4 choices, how would I put in a CASE:WHEN... or a SWITCH?

Comment: Probably easiest approach would be use chaining of ternary operators, like this: <field>==<case1>?<result1>:<field>==<case2>?<result2>:.....:<default result>